# Expression that means "sorry"

Tags: выражения

I used to speak with a Russian speaker and she used to repeat something 3 times after she said something bad, it sounded like "steraï steraï steraï".
If you see what I'm talking about, can you help me writing it in Russian ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: the most and the only similar word I can recall with your example is "стирай" which can mean either "wipe, erase etc." or "wash, do laundry" (in the imperative "mood" — or what is the correct linguistic term for this). May be she was trying to say "sorry" in English, but you misunderstood her?

Comment: Maybe this is this expression, but she said you have to repeat it 3 times. The meaning seems right, and I'm sure it was not english, she is fluent in english and she used to say it, it didn't happen only once..

Comment: Or it might have meant "delete" the record, if you were speaking via some digital media and she had thought, that you might have been recording her

Comment: No, for example when I said "you will fail something" I had to say "steraï" 3 times to erase the negative thing I said.

Comment: There is a superstition, that when you wish someone good luck you can say "ни пуха ни пера" literally "no down, no feather" ( I have no idea of the etymology of this) and your counterpart should respond with "к черту" (which means sort of "to the devil", but I have never heard it should be repeated three times). There is another superstition, that when one says that something bad is going to happen or might happen, then he should spit three times over his left shoulder and knock on wood (not necessarily three times). Unless your speaker is 16yo and uses some modern slang from some subculture

Comment: Yes you're right it's probably something about superstition, she is 20, but I don't know whether it does matter. The expressions you listed doesn't sound the same, maybe it depends on the place, or on the culture ?

Comment: I mean, that how old is she does matter, because from my experience many "youngsters" in Russia at least, use quite a few words, which not every native Russian speaker would understand. There might be some new "superstition" or other "rave" , which is not widely known etc.

Comment: I think that it's not something new since she moved from Russia to another country when she was young and doesn't live in Russia for 15 years but they still speak in Russian in her family, I don't know if that helps you :/

Comment: then the only my suggestion is from the previous comment about "к черту"

Comment: I think that this one "стирай" sounds really similar as what she used to say, but they say it's bulgarian on google translate, is it ?

Comment: no it's Russian "стирать" (to wash, to erase) in the imperative mood, when one gives an order to do some action. As in English it would be "wash", "erase"

Comment: Oki, I think it's the word that I was looking for, thanks a lot !

Comment: the word "стирай" actually makes no sense to me, in that context

Comment: I don't know, it really sounds similar so maybe it's not but it would be a big coincidence.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just ask her? Let us all off the hook! ;)

Comment: Well I cannot talk to her at the moment, the situation is complexe.. But if I get an answer one day, I won't forget to add it here ^^'

Comment: when you were talking, was she ONLY talking to you, or was she maybe doing something at her place at this point? She could really just say to herself. Example, she was cleaning some mails or files from computer, or photos from camera, then at the moments of most tension she could be "saying bitter things" and stopping doing her whores, then "wipe, wipe, wipe" could be her forcing herself to re-start DOING things not merely talking. Or she could be washing laundry, then "wash, wash, wash" could be her returning herself to living and moving state.

Comment: additionally, could she at that moment be speaking some other language than Russian/French ? did she sometimes used words from other languages? If that was like "superstition" she could be repeating some fancy ritual she could saw in a cinema or read in book or anything. Twice so for you say "moved from Russia to another country when she was young and doesn't live in Russia for 15 years" - and which country that is? maybe you better query the language of her new local neighbors?

Comment: Oh, the question none of us even mentioned yet. When she was spelling those "steraï steraï steraï", which of the vowels was accented/stressed, E or A ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

steraï steraï steraï or `Стирай, Стирай, Стирай` I think she wants you to erase something.

Comment: Could someone who understands this answer please correct the spelling and grammar? I only ask because I honestly do not know what it is saying.

Answer (score 4):

It could be "стирай" indeed. All people are different and have their own, so to speak, traditions. Some people say "тьфу-тьфу-тьфу", some people prefer to use the phrase "типун мне на язык", maybe she likes to say "стирай" when she wants to "erase" some bad thoughts and statements so they don't come true.

Comment: Yes you're probably right, I think it's about traditions :)

Answer (score 3):

A hypothesis: it could be **про**(**сти**, про)(**сти**, **про**)сти (forgive, forgive, forgive), where the unstressed **о** sounds like **a**.

Comment: или расти-расти-расти //
или стервь-стервь-стервь :-D

Comment: Doesn't sound like the answerer answers, it could sounds like this "расти" but I'm pretty sure that it started by "st" (this sound)

Answer (score 0):

It could be the superstitional "тьфу-тьфу-тьфу", or even "чур-чур-чур" as in "чур меня", both often accompanied by spitting over one's left shoulder. The first option is more common to encounter, while the second one matches the pronunciation better, but, nevertheless, both have been traditionally aimed at protecting the speaker against unholy forces.

Comment: For sure it's not that, it doesn't sound as I described it at all, the expression sounded more like "стирай".

Comment: Maybe could be like that, just not in Russian. You said she lived most of her life in another country